# BrowserslistError(name) on gulp build

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I tried to setup project with gulp. I am using gulpfile.js that I used on many previous projects, but now I get error BrowserslistError that looks like this:

```
{project_root}/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:38
throw new BrowserslistError(name);
^
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `var browserslist = require('./');`
at error ({project_root}/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:38:11)
at {project_root}/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:246:9
at Array.forEach (native)
at browserslist ({project_root}/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:214:13)
at cleanBrowsersList ({project_root}/node_modules/caniuse-api/dist/utils.js:56:59)
at setBrowserScope ({project_root}/node_modules/caniuse-api/dist/index.js:26:43)
at Object.<anonymous> ({project_root}/node_modules/caniuse-api/dist/index.js:88:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
```

I tried to remove node_modules folder and to reinstall npm but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar issue few days back. I was missing browserslist declaration in my package.json

Try adding this (or similar) to your package.json:

```
...
"browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "android 4",
    "opera 12"
]
...
```